# Show generated code from lisp macro

Tags: macros, lisp

I am very new to lisp and this may well be a very stupid/obvious question but in common lisp can you show the generated code from a  macro ?

So for the example

```
(defmacro nil! (var)
  (list 'setq var nil))
```

I'd like to be able see the expanded code

```
(setq a nil)
```

Comment: Try `macroexpand` or `macroexpand-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Diego said... [MACROEXPAND-1](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mexp_.htm).

```
* (macroexpand-1 '(nil! frob))

(SETQ FROB NIL)
T
*
```

Comment: Thankyou, I thought it must be simple.

Comment: @DeanSmith: After prodding your macro a bit: I'd suggest rewriting it to `(defmacro nil! (var)
  \`(setf ,var nil))`. SETF is more general and usually more appropriate than SETQ.  The quasiquote is less verbose and more common in macroology.